# Variable in feed url in mailchimp

Tags: rss, mailchimp

Using mailchimp to send RSS-driven campaigns. Fetching the RSS from a WP installation. This works fine.

In the end of the email I want to add one RSS-item from another source with mailchimps merge tag `*|FEED|*` as shown in this tutorial: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-add-any-blog-post-to-a-regular-campaign

I got this to work with a static URL. But I want to use different URL:s depending on the recipient. I've saved the URL:s with mailchimps API in a merge tag called `*|USER_FEED_URL|*` and I can print this URL perfectly, but is there a way to use the feed tag with my user_feed_url and fetch the RSS?

Tried: `*|FEED:*|USER_FEED_URL|*|*`

But it only print: `*|FEED:http://theuserurl.com/feed|*`

Comment: I don't believe you can use merge tags inside of merge tags in MaiLChimp. You may consider an alternative solution, like conditional merge tags, depending on the variety of feeds you need to insert. Can you explain a bit about the user_feed_url? Is that literally unique for each subscriber or are they just links to different specific feeds (like feed categories)?

Comment: I thought it was impossible. The user_feed_url is not unique for every subscriber, but there are atleast 50 different. So conditional merge tags would work, but not dynamically.

Comment: Ever got this working? I'm having the exact same problem here. In my case it's 250+ different combinations :(

Comment: No. It was impossible.